# Android Audio Media Recorder stop failed

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

```
public class RecordCallService extends Service {

public final static String ACTION_START_RECORDING = "com.ss.ACTION_CLEAN_UP";
public final static String ACTION_STOP_RECORDING = "com.ss.ACTION_STOP_RECORDING";
public final static String EXTRA_PHONE_CALL = "com.ss.EXTRA_PHONE_CALL";

public RecordCallService(){
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    ContentValues parcelableExtra = intent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_PHONE_CALL);
    startRecording(new CallLog(parcelableExtra));
    return START_NOT_STICKY ;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stopRecording();
    super.onDestroy();
}

private CallLog phoneCall;

boolean isRecording = false;

private void stopRecording() {

    if (isRecording) {
        try {
            phoneCall.setEndTime(Calendar.getInstance());
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            mediaRecorder.reset();
            mediaRecorder.release();
            mediaRecorder = null;
            isRecording = false;

            phoneCall.save(getBaseContext());
            displayNotification(phoneCall);

            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(new Intent(LocalBroadcastActions.NEW_RECORDING_BROADCAST));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    phoneCall = null;
}


MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;


private void startRecording(CallLog phoneCall) {
    if (!isRecording) {
        isRecording = true;
        this.phoneCall = phoneCall;
        File file = null;
        try {
            this.phoneCall.setSartTime(Calendar.getInstance());
            File dir = AppPreferences.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getFilesDirectory();
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            file = File.createTempFile("record", ".3gp", dir);
            this.phoneCall.setPathToRecording(file.getAbsolutePath());
            mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
            mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);
            mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(12200);
            mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(phoneCall.getPathToRecording());
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
            mediaRecorder.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            isRecording = false;
            if (file != null) file.delete();
            this.phoneCall = null;
            isRecording = false;
        }
    }
}

public void displayNotification(CallLog phoneCall) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_recording_conversation_white_24);
    builder.setContentTitle(getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.notification_title));
    builder.setContentText(getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.notification_text));
    builder.setContentInfo(getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.notification_more_text));
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    intent.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis())); // fake action to force PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    intent.putExtra("RecordingId", phoneCall.getId());

    builder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0xFeed, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
    notificationManager.notify(0xfeed, builder.build());
}


public static void sartRecording(Context context, CallLog phoneCall) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, RecordCallService.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_START_RECORDING);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PHONE_CALL, phoneCall.getContent());
    context.startService(intent);
}


public static void stopRecording(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, RecordCallService.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_STOP_RECORDING);
    context.stopService(intent);
}


}
```

This is my code

Now Is My Logcat

```
 12-05 01:44:52.599 6356-6356/com.ss.automaticrecorder I/SSCALLRECORDER: MyCallReceiver.onReceive 
 12-05 01:44:52.683 6356-6356/com.ss.automaticrecorder E/MediaRecorder: stop failed: -1007
 12-05 01:44:52.683 6356-6356/com.ss.automaticrecorder W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: stop failed.
 12-05 01:44:52.687 6356-6356/com.ss.automaticrecorder W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)
 12-05 01:44:52.688 6356-6356/com.ss.automaticrecorder W/System.err:     at com.ss.automaticrecorder.services.RecordCallService.stopRecording(RecordCallService.java:65)
 12-05 01:44:52.688 6356-6356/com.ss.automaticrecorder W/System.err:     at com.ss.automaticrecorder.services.RecordCallService.onDestroy(RecordCallService.java:52)
 12-05 01:44:52.688 6356-6356/com.ss.automaticrecorder W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopService(ActivityThread.java:3058)
 12-05 01:44:52.688 6356-6356/com.ss.automaticrecorder W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:153)
 12-05 01:44:52.688 6356-6356/com.ss.automaticrecorder W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1450)
 12-05 01:44:52.688 6356-6356/com.ss.automaticrecorder W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 12-05 01:44:52.688 6356-6356/com.ss.automaticrecorder W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
 12-05 01:44:52.688 6356-6356/com.ss.automaticrecorder W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451)
 12-05 01:44:52.688 6356-6356/com.ss.automaticrecorder W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 12-05 01:44:52.688 6356-6356/com.ss.automaticrecorder W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
 12-05 01:44:52.688 6356-6356/com.ss.automaticrecorder W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 12-05 01:44:57.677 6356-6475/com.ss.automaticrecorder V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
 12-05 01:45:06.528 6356-6356/com.ss.automaticrecorder I/SSCALLRECORDER: MyCallReceiver.onReceive
```

I Dont Know Where is The Mistake as this code runs perfectly on other manufacturers like samsung,lenovo but the problem comes in vision when on asus zenfone series 
As the logcat shows stop is being called before start but it seems i have done it right
im using media recorder for more info